# Lazy evaluation not working as it should

Tags: java, lazy-evaluation

I had to evaluate a boolean expression frecuently, so I converted it in a private method in it's class. Here is the code it's causing me trouble:

```
//"x", "y" and "team" are already defined
return (map.isWalkable(x,y) && 
    (!map.isOccupied(x,y) || map.getOccupant(x, y).getTeam() == team) );
```

Methods should be preety much self-explanatory as for the purpose of this question. Now, isWalkable and isOccupied both return a boolean, and getOccupant is the only method returning an object reference. The problem is that I'm getting a NullPointerException when executing this piece of code, and that shouldn't be happening because isOccupied returns true if and only if map.getOccupant != null (that's actually what that method returns). So with a language supporting lazy boolean evaluation from left to right (as I assume java is, or at least that's what I was able to read) the getOccupant method should never be executed whenever it would return null am I right?

Is this more compiler-dependent than I thought it was? Should it be safer if I used if statements, or is there simply something obvious I'm missing here, maybe operations get resolved the other way round.

Comment: I think you have one closing parenthesis too much after getTeam().

Comment: This is so easy to debug yourself, why ask here? Assign each subresult to its own variable and print them/test them for `null`. It's a 3-minute job, if you're slow.

Comment: I'm quite sure this is not the original code (since it has a parsing problem with your closing brackets), so how do we know you didn't make an other mistake indeed?

Comment: One of your closing circular bracket seems to be misplaced. Does it even compile?

Comment: Crap. Seems like I got confused with your statement. The real issue is with the unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: @I edited the unbalanced parentheses thing. That couldn't cause a runtime exception anyway so I don't know why so many people pointed that to be the problem, that wouldn't even compile. I was casting getOccupant to another type in the original code and deleted the first parentheses but not the last one, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your parenthesis. Try

```
return (map.isWalkable(x,y) && (!map.isOccupied(x,y) || map.getOccupant(x, y).getTeam() == team));
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I edited the question to fix it but it wasn't what was causing the exception.

Comment: A NullPointerException would only be thrown in two cases of this code: either `map` is null, and the exception is thrown when you try to execute a method on a `null` object, or the return of `map.getOccupant(x,y)` is null, and the exception gets thrown because you're trying to call `getTeam()` on a `null` object.

Comment: Yes, the question is already answered, but I couldn't mark it as answered that quickly as SO doesn't let me. But thank you anyway.

EDIT: Well it seems not. Someone erased the answer I was going to accept...

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, no, lazy evaluation is not broken. Your code is.
Either `map` is null, or `map.getOccupant(x,y)` returns null.

If you put them on their own lines and go through them with a debugger, you'll notice that "oh no, I was so stupid and didn't notice that".

The compiler, JVM or anything else has nothing to do with this.